# How to pass functions as parameters within a class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, pointer-to-member

I am trying to pass my `print` function as a paramater through my `inordertraversal` class which belongs to a templated `binarySearchTree`. whenever I define these functions within main the program works fine but whenever i try to encapsulate them I get a error:

```
"expected primary-expression before '&' token"
```

This is the code that works

```
void print(classdatatype& x); 
int main()
{
    binarySearchTree<classdatatype> tree;
    tree.inorderTraversal(print);
    return 0;
}

void print(classdatatype& x)   {  cout << x << " ";      }
```

The declaration of my `inordertraveral` templated class is

```
template <class elemType>
void binarySearchTree<elemType>::inorderTraversal(void (*visit)(elemType& item))
```

I can show the rest of the code if needed but this all works just fine

Once I move these functions into my class it looks like this
(the declarations for `print` and the `binarySearchTree` are in the *.cpp* same as they are declared above)

```
void bst::printfunctions(classdatatype& x)
{
    tree.inorderTraversal(print(classdatatype & x)); //error here
}

void bst::print(classdatatype& x) 
{ 
    cout << x << " "; 
}
```

The error is to do within the brackets of `print`, I have tried many different things but to me this is the correct declaration; therefore I don't know why it's not working.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: `print` is a function pointer to print the details of `classdatatype` which is stored inside a binary search tree.

---

**EDIT2**: minimal reproducible example.

Data types are as they are and not like in the above example. This is as basic as I could make this and I ended up getting another error which I couldn't resolve but for the purpose of this example it doesn't matter and should be ignored. 
`main()` is included but is minimal and may not serve its purpose but the problem doesn't lie here anyway.

**main()**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windlogtype.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    windlogtype wind;

    ifstream infile("data.txt");
    //for purose of this data is one integer value
    infile >> wind;

    //do something
    //main purpose is to get input
    return 0;
}
```

**class `windlogtype`**

```
#include "windlogtype.h"
windlogtype::windlogtype() { }    
windlogtype::windlogtype(int i)     {   num = i; }    
int windlogtype::Getnumber() const  {   return num; }    
void windlogtype::Setnumber(int i)  {   num = i; }    
ostream operator<<(ostream& os, const windlogtype& w)
{
    os << w.Getnumber() << '\n';
    return os;
}

#ifndef WINDLOGTYPE_H
#define WINDLOGTYPE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class windlogtype
{
public:
    windlogtype();
    windlogtype(int i);
    int Getnumber() const;
    void Setnumber(int i);
private:
    int num;
};
ostream operator<<(ostream& os, const windlogtype& w);

#endif // WINDLOGTYPE_H
```

**class `binarySearchTree`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

template <class elemType> struct binaryTreeNode
{
    elemType info;
    binaryTreeNode<elemType>* llink;
    binaryTreeNode<elemType>* rlink;
};

template <class elemType> class binarySearchTree
{
public:
    const binarySearchTree<elemType>& operator=(const binarySearchTree<elemType>&);
    void inorderTraversal(void (*visit) (elemType&));
    binarySearchTree();
    ~binarySearchTree();
    binaryTreeNode<elemType>* root;
private:
    void inorder(binaryTreeNode<elemType>* p, void (*visit) (elemType&));
};

template <class elemType> binarySearchTree<elemType>::binarySearchTree() {
    root = NULL;
}    
template <class elemType> void binarySearchTree<elemType>::inorderTraversal(void (*visit) (elemType& item))
{
    inorder(root, *visit);
}    
template <class elemType> void binarySearchTree<elemType>::inorder(binaryTreeNode<elemType>* p, void (*visit) (elemType& item))
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->llink, *visit);
        (*visit)(p->info);
        inorder(p->rlink, *visit);
    }
}
```

**class `bst`**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H
#include "binarySearchTree.h"
#include "windlogtype.h"
using namespace std;

class bst
{
public:
    bst();
    void InsertTree(windlogtype& newwind);
    void printfunctions(windlogtype& x);
    binarySearchTree<windlogtype>& GetTree();
    void print(windlogtype& x);
private:
    binarySearchTree<windlogtype> treeRoot;
};    
#endif // BST_H

#include "bst.h"

bst::bst(){/*ctor*/ }    
binarySearchTree<windlogtype>& bst::GetTree() {     return treeRoot;  }
void bst::print(windlogtype& x)               {     cout << x << " ";  }
void bst::printfunctions(windlogtype& x)
{
    treeRoot.inorderTraversal(print(windlogtype & x)); // error lies here
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `std::function` as parameter type?

Comment: i'm pretty new to c++ and i'm not sure what std::function even is or how to use it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: When you moved the function into your class, did you make it `static`?  It would be better if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: Just for clarification:  are you trying to pass `print` from `bst` class to `inorderTraversal` of `binarySearchTree<elemType>` class ?

Comment: @Eljay no i didnt, i'll make an edit containing more detailed example

Comment: @JeJo Yes that is correct, print is a function pointer to print the details of classdatatype which is stored inside a binary search tree.

Comment: Printing a single element of a collection does not belong in a collection interface. `void print(classdatatype& x)` is Ok. `void classdatatype::print()` would also be Ok. `void bst::print(classdatatype& x)` is wrong. Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

The

```
void bst::print(classdatatype& x) // is a member function
```

and

```
void print(classdatatype& x);    // is a free function.
```

Hence the [function pointers to hold them](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) will be also different.

---

The OP has mentioned in the comments, that he/she wants to pass the member function `print()` from `bst` class to member function`inorderTraversal()` of `binarySearchTree<elemType>` class. In that case **passing the *member-function* is not sufficient, in addition to that the instance of the class to which the `print` function will be called also should be passed**.

The *[Lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)* function can come in handy to simplify this by capturing the instance of `bst` class and pass to the `inorderTraversal()` of the `binarySearchTree` class.

That means, inside `template <class elemType> class binarySearchTree` provide:

```
template<typename Callable>
void inorderTraversal(Callable visit)
{
    inorder(root, visit);  // simply pass visit further
    // or avoid coping by warapping std::cref(): i.e. inorder(root, std::cref(visit));
}

template<typename Callable>
void inorder(binaryTreeNode<elemType>* p, Callable visit)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->llink, visit);  // or inorder(root, std::cref(visit));
        visit(p->info);            // call directly with parameter
        inorder(p->rlink, visit);  // or inorder(root, std::cref(visit));
    }
}
```

Inside the `bst` class

```
void printfunctions(windlogtype& x)
{
    // lambda captures the instance by copy
    const auto printThisLogType = [this](windlogtype & x)->void { this->print(x); };
    treeRoot.inorderTraversal(printThisLogType); // pass the callable lambda
}
```

Here is compiling code: https://godbolt.org/z/jhCnPs

---

**PS**: The other error was from `operator<<` of `windlogtype` class where you missed to return the reference of `std::ostream`.

To be honest, you could have made a further simpler minimal code, by replacing `windlogtype` with `int` and showing the defenitions of the member function next to the declaration. That would make the code to read easily.